# React router 3 wont render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to go to a route that shows a sidebar and some content but I get `undefined` as part of my route and it just goes to a blank page. I am not quite sure why this is happening but any help would be appreciated. I am pretty sure it has to do with there not being a route to get the courseId as a parameter, but I am not sure how to nest that in or how to get it to work.

Here are my routes:

```js
import App from './components/App'
import Course from './routes/Course/components/Course'
import AnnouncementsSidebar from './routes/Course/routes/Announcements/components/Sidebar'
import Announcements from './routes/Course/routes/Announcements/components/Announcements'
import Announcement from './routes/Course/routes/Announcements/routes/Announcement/components/Announcement'
import AssignmentsSidebar from './routes/Course/routes/Assignments/components/Sidebar'
import Assignments from './routes/Course/routes/Assignments/components/Assignments'
import Assignment from './routes/Course/routes/Assignments/routes/Assignment/components/Assignment'

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="course/:courseId" component={Course}>
        <Route path="announcements" components={{
          sidebar: AnnouncementsSidebar,
          main: Announcements
        }}>
          <Route path=":announcementId" component={Announcement} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="assignments" components={{
          sidebar: AssignmentsSidebar,
          main: Assignments
        }}>
          <Route path=":assignmentId" component={Assignment} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Here is the course component:

```js
/*globals SideNavData:true */
const styles = {}

styles.sidebar = {
  float: 'left',
  width: 200,
  padding: 20,
  borderRight: '1px solid #aaa',
  marginRight: 20
}

class Course extends Component {
  render() {
    let { sidebar, main, children, params } = this.props
    let course = SideNavData[params.courseId]

    let content
    if (sidebar && main) {
      content = (
        <div>
          <div className="Sidebar" style={styles.sidebar}>
            {sidebar}
          </div>
          <div className="Main" style={{ padding: 20 }}>
            {main}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    } else if (children) {
      content = children
    } else {
      content = <Dashboard />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{course.name}</h2>
        <Nav course={course} />
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Course
```

here is a codesandbox if needed: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw0xvj6r0m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading `courseId` from router params but there isn't that parameter in Root route in `Course` component on line 19.

`let course = SideNavData[params.courseId];`

That is why when clicking link in you Nav component it redirects you to /course/undefined/...

EDIT:
Actually, you never reference that parameter in your Router... So you will always have undefined course

Comment: I was able to add a home, and that param (edited snippets above) but I didn't really want it like this, I wanted to remove the one layer of routes and just initially land on the course links. Would you know how to do that?

Here is the Home component:

```class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GlobalNav />
        <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          {this.props.children || <Dashboard courses={COURSES} />}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}```

the code sandbox is aso updated for a better picture

Comment: I don't get it, as far as I see your code is now working. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes it is. but I didnt want to add a home component or route there. I wanted the get rid of that route and just have the Course component to be the home with its routes and sidebar